# Saving png image with Java using JFileChooser

Tags: java, image, swing, file-io, javax.imageio

I am trying to save an image that is formed with a BufferedImage.  I get the BufferedImage by doing

```
(BufferedImage) fg;
```

fg is an image of my jPanel's graphics.  I am successful at saving the image by hardcoding the path in directly as follows:

```
ImageIO.write((BufferedImage)fg,"png",new File("C:\\Users\\Geiger\\Documents\\test.png"));
```

But when I attempt to add the JFileChooser to the mix the image that is saved comes up being blank with nothing but the jPanel's background color.

My code for my attempt at utilizing the JFileChooser is as follows:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
int retVal = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
if(retVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    String test = f.getAbsolutePath();
    ImageIO.write((BufferedImage)fg,"png",new File(test));
 }
```

EDIT:To clarify on the issue a little bit more:
The issue is not that a file doesn't appear its that the graphics don't appear on the image when using the JFileChooser object.

I update my image when the JFrame has a mouse presses event:

```
fg = jPanel2.createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
```

Comment: Make sure that the file reference you are writing to is a actually a File and not a directory

Comment: Why not just `ImageIO.write((BufferedImage) fg, "png", jfc.getSelectedFile())`? No need to create a new file object pointing to the same path. However, the problem is most likely not in the code you have posted, but in the way you update your `fg` image.

Comment: @haraldk - I have tried that, but the file still comes up blank with the gray background of the jPanel.

Comment: I didn't expect it to solve any problem, just make the code better. As I said, *the problem is most likely not in the code you have posted, but in the way you update your image*. Try posting that part of the code, or better, create an SSCCE, and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 2):

try to put this line of code I think that's what you need:

```
ImageIO.write(buffer, "png", fileDialog.getSelectedFile());
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
scribblePane.paint(graphics2D);
```

Use these two lines of code to add graphics.

Answer (score 0):

That's works for me

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.png", "png"));
    if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            ImageIO.write((BufferedImage) image, "png", new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to save image!");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file choosen!");
    }
}
```